# Override height property

Tags: css

I have an element which inherits a height of 40px.

However, the element I need to style is a textarea box, with variable height / width. How would I 'cancel' the height of an element, such that there is no height property for the element and it can be resized?

Comment: Do you mean that the textarea should switch size after what size of the content is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply want to make your textarea element able to be resized, try just applying the following CSS property:

```css
textarea {
    resize: both;
}
```

[An example can be seen here](http://jsfiddle.net/W863X/) where the height is set, but using the resize property, it can still be resized.

Answer (score 17):

To override a set height in a CSS element, you can simply put this in the inherited element (either in a style block or inline):

```
height: auto;
```

This will override the set value inherited, without statically setting a new one.

Answer (score 9):

Another way is to use height auto with !important marker:

```
height: auto !important;
```

'important' will make things work, but if this HTML is then imported by someone else, they won't be able to override this marker. So my advice is **use only when extremely necessary**.